# Cannot connect to azure PostresSQL database - The Username should be in <username@hostname> format

Tags: postgresql, azure, go

I cannot connect to an Azure PostgreSQL database in a Golang application

Error message :

```
FATAL: Invalid Username specified. Please check the Username and retry connection. The Username should be in <username@hostname> format. (SQLSTATE 28000))
```

I do not have an @ in my username.

I am using gorm as a ORM and connecting like this

```golang
dbUrl := fmt.Sprintf("postgres://%s:%s@%s:5432/%s", dbUser, dbPass, dbHost, dbName)
db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dbUrl), &gorm.Config{})
```

My variables look like this

```
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="password!"
DB_HOST="some-url-with-dashes.postgres.database.azure.com"
APP_PORT="8080"
POSTGRES_USER="postgresuser"
DB_NAME="file"
```

My code does see them and correctly creates `dbUrl` like :

```
postgres://postgresuser:password!@some-url-with-dashes.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/file
```

I have tried changing the username and password

Comment: That does not look like an error message PostgreSQL would generate.  It is either coming from the system and PostgreSQL is just passing it along (unlikely I think) or is being generated by some secret sauce MS has crammed into their fork.  Or maybe GORM has captured the real error message and rewritten it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have configured the parameter [`db_user_namespace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-DB-USER-NAMESPACE) to `on`. Don't do that.